Dynamic import on Chrome for windows get stuck since today
I have many apps using dynamic import of javascript modules working for years.
Since today they are no longer working on chrome for windows.
The code line
const def = await import("../main.mjs");

is never returning nor throwing an exception (Its surrounded by try/catch)
On all other Browsers its still working fine.
Any suggestions?

The fact that it doesn't display any error make me think about this post but it's weird since you said it has been working for years.

I have the same issue and am currently looking into it further. So far I've found it's somehow linked the imported file, importing other files.
Testing with this:
const modTest = await import('./test.js');
modTest.default('hello');

This version of test.js never resolves.
// test.js
import testFn from './test-copy.js';

export default function mainFn(str) {
  console.log('MOD:', str);
  testFn('hello');
}

This version of test.js works.
// test.js
export default function mainFn(str) {
  console.log('MOD:', str);
}

This is not the full story however. I tried reproducing this issue in a blank project and haven't had any luck.
UPDATE:
I found a fix for our specific case.
So it looks like top level awaits mess up dynamic imports that have their own imports.
Here is my test setup:
Basic HTML
...
<script defer src="one.js" type="module"></script>
...

// one.js
export default async function main() {
  document.querySelector('.for-one').textContent = 'hello one';
  const module = await import('./two.js');
  await module.default();
}
export const twoMsg = 'hello two'

main()
const res = await fetch('https://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes');

// two.js
import { twoMsg } from './one.js';

export default async function main(str) {
  document.querySelector('.for-two').textContent = twoMsg;
}

If run like this, the function from two.js is never run, as the promise of the import is never resolved. However if I remove the top-level await fetch from one.js it all works fine. So this issue can be solved by wrapping the whole thing in an async function.
This is probably a bug in chrome since top-level awaits should be supported in modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#browser_compatibility
One thing is still a bit confusing though... The line in our project where we encounter this issue uses the exact same code as in two other projects but those other two have no issues. Which leads me to believe this goes deeper. But I won't dig anymore, the issue can be worked around for our case.

Could you try to reduce the imported file in the imported file to a minimum to maybe find some more infos what is causing the problem?

Thx for all your work. Will try this asap and report here. Maybe I can help also a bit but atm I am 150% busy on work. Please don’t be bothered that I do not set this answer as the result as there is place for improvement
